transmit pmt output over long distance cable
I made a pmt driver using the example provide in the hamamatsu pmt handbook and the driver has also has a 5 V PWM control signal to toggle on and off the PMT. PWM frequency will be 7 kHz.
I would like to transmit this control signals and PMT output uA signal over distance of 2.5-3 meters, where the FPGA will process the signal.
I tried putting an amplifier circuit on the output of PMT which converts output current to differential pair. This works perfectly fine on small flat flex or ribbon cable with length of 0.2 meter. When I tried long cable I get reflections on the control signal and noise in the differential output signal.
These signal are running in industrial environment with lots of power cable and other signal cable near it.
My questions:
Is possible to use 4-20 mA loop on the pmt output? Because the 4-20 mA loop should be lot more tolerant to noise.
Should I also use a line driver like am26ls31 for the control signal?

Put a transimpedance amplifier as close as possible to the tube then is a 50 ohm coaxial cable and terminate at the load end to prevent reflections.
